# Creating PerformanceCounterCategory in Powershell

Tags: powershell, performancecounter

I'm trying to run the following script in powershell:

```
$counters = @()

$counters = $counters + [Diagnostics.CounterCreationData]::("Hit counter", "Number of total hits", [Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterType]::NumberOfItem32);
$counters = $counters + [Diagnostics.CounterCreationData]::("Hits per second", "Number of average hits per second", [Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterType]::RateOfCountsPerSecond32);

$counterCollection = [Diagnostics.CounterCreationDataCollection]::($counters);

[Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategory]::Create("HitCounters","Some help text",[Diagnostics.PerformanceCounterCategoryType]::SingleInstance, $counterCollection);
```

When I execute this, I get an error saying $counterCollection is null.
I'm afraid I'm not yet familiar enough with powershell to sort out where this is going wrong - is it the array I'm building the Collection from? Or the CounterCreationDataCollection creation call itself?

Any pointers are more than welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mixing in static accessor syntax `::` with the constructor call.  Try this instead:

```
$ccdTypeName = 'System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationDate'
$ccdcTypeName = 'System.Diagnostics.CounterCreationDataCollection'
$counters = @()
$counters += new-object $ccdTypeName "Hit counter","..."
$counters += new-object $ccdTypeName "Hits per sec","..."
$counterCollection = new-object $ccdcTypeName $counters
...
```